# IF test against ARG_MAX and number of files in directory

Tags: bash, macos

I have potentially a large number of generated files and subdirectories in a directory for which the number is not known ahead of execution.   For simplicity,  lets say I just want to invoke

```
mv * /another_dir/.
```

But for large numbers of files and subdirectories, it'll come back with the dreaded 'argument too long'.    Yes I know find and xargs is a way to deal with it.  But I want to test that number against ARG_MAX and try it that way first.

I'm on a Mac and so I can't up the ulimit setting.

So far I have

```
# max_value
if ((expr `getconf ARG_MAX` - `env|wc -c` - `env|wc -l` \* 4 - 2048)  ) ; then echo "ok" ; fi
```

which offers me a value to test against.

Lets say my test value to compute number of files or subdirectories  in directory is based on

```
# test_value
(find . -maxdepth 1 | wc -l)
```

How can I get a working expression  no matter how many files

```
if (test_value < max_value ) ; then echo "do this" else echo "do that" ; fi
```

Every way I try to construct the if test, the syntax fails for some reason in trying to set the max_value and test_value parameters and then test them together.  Grateful for help.

Comment: Why not just `find` and `mv` together?

Comment: Have you tried double parens? Like `((test_value < max_value))`

Comment: @oguzismail  I have problems to set test_value and max_value first,  not sure why

Comment: @trojanfoe    I could,  but I want to work out a way to section out when I can expand * without problems and use mv directly on the expansion without involving a find operation (which I agree is relatively trivial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing shell scripts, you have to pay a lot of attention to what context you're in, and use the right syntax for that context. The thing that goes between `if` and `then` is treated as a command, so you could use e.g. `if expr 2 \> 1; then`. But the modern replacement of the `expr` command is the `(( ))` arithmetic expression, so you'd use `if (( 2 > 1 )); then`. Note that you don't need to escape the `>` because it's no longer part of a regular command, and that you *cannot* put spaces between the parentheses `( ( something ) )` does something completely different from `(( something ))`.

`(( ))` lets you run a calculation/comparison/etc as though it were a command. It's also common to want to use the result of a calculation *as part of* a command; for that, use `$(( ))`:

```
max_value=$(($(getconf ARG_MAX) - $(env|wc -c) - $(env|wc -l) * 4 - 2048))
test_value=$(ls -A | wc -l)
```

Note that I used `$( )` instead of backticks; it does essentially the same thing, with somewhat cleaner syntax. And again, the arrangement of parentheses matter: `$(( ))` does a calculation and captures its result; `$( )` runs a command and captures its output. And `$( ( ) )` would run a command in a pointless sub-subshell and capture its output. Oh, and I used `ls -A` because `find . -maxdepth 1` will include `.` (the current directory) in its output, giving an overcount of 1. (And both the `find` and `ls` versions will miscount files with linefeeds in their name; oh, well.)

Then, to do the final comparison:

```
if ((test_value < max_value)) ; then echo "do this" else echo "do that" ; fi
```